# how to get [x,y] position related to the clicked div border?

Tags: javascript

how to get [x,y] position related to the clicked div border?

this position of the clicked box is random , the example bellow is only one situation. I want to get click point position related to the clicked div , how to do it in js ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>img click positon</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('.clickbox').bind('click',function(e){
                // how to get [x,y] positon relatived to div.clickbox ?
                // console.log(x,y);
            })
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{margin:0;padding:0}
        .page{margin:0 auto; width:940px}
        .box{width:200px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10%}
        .clickbox{width:100%; height:230px;background-color:tan;}
    </style>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="clickbox"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div.clickbox').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    console.log("X: "+e.clientX - offset.left);
    console.log("Y: "+e.clientY - offset.top);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.clickbox').bind('click',function(e){
         var offset = $(this).offset();
         alert(e.clientX - offset.left);
         alert(e.clientY - offset.top);
     })
});
</script>
```

Comment: e.pageX,e.pageY is relatived to window ,  I clicked the border of the clicked div , it returns not 0 but hundreds .

Answer (score 1):

```
e.pageX and e.pageY
```

You also find the offset- and the screen-coordinates in the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: e.pageX,e.pageY is relatived to window , I clicked the border of the clicked div , it returns not 0 but hundreds.

Comment: Didn't took that into account, I think Norbert Pisz's answer does what  you expect.